# Struts2 file upload not working in production, but working in local development

Tags: html, tomcat, file-upload, struts2

i am trying to create a webpage that has the file upload feature.

FileUpload.jsp

```
<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>

<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>file upload Page</title>
</head>
<body bgColor="lightBlue">
     <s:form action="fileUpload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        <s:file name="userTmp" label="File" />
        <br/>
        <s:submit value="uploadFile"/>
    </s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Struts.xml

```
<package name="upload" namespace="/FileUpload" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="fileUpload" class="FileUploadAction">
            <result name="success">success.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">error.jsp</result>
        </action>
</package>
```

FileUploadAction.java

```
public class FileUploadAction  extends ActionSupport{


    private File userTmp;

    private String userTmpContentType;

    private String userTmpFileName;


Connection conn = null;

    public String execute() throws Exception
    {
           String result = ERROR;
           try {  
               Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
               conn= DriverManager.getConnection(".....");  

               System.out.println("DATABASE CONNECTED");  
               String sql = "insert into Evidence(Filename, FileType, FileContent,DateSubmitted) values(?, ?, ?, now())";
                   PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);  
                   FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(userTmp); 
                   pstmt.setString(1, userTmpFileName);
                   pstmt.setString(2, userTmpContentType);
                   pstmt.setBinaryStream(3, fis, (int)userTmp.length()); 
                   pstmt.executeUpdate(); 
                   pstmt.close(); 
                   fis.close(); 
                   result = SUCCESS;
             }             
             catch (Exception e) {  
                 e.printStackTrace();  
             }
             finally  
             {  
                 conn.close();  
             }  

          return result;
    }

    public File getUserTmp() {
        return userTmp;
    }

    public void setUserTmp(File userTmp) {
        this.userTmp = userTmp;
    }

    public String getUserTmpContentType() {
        return userTmpContentType;
    }

    public void setUserTmpContentType(String userTmpContentType) {
        this.userTmpContentType = userTmpContentType;
    }

    public String getUserTmpFileName() {
        return userTmpFileName;
    }

    public void setUserTmpFileName(String userTmpFileName) {
        this.userTmpFileName = userTmpFileName;
    }

}
```

This is working fine when i am running it on my local tomcat server.

But when I deployed it on a different tomcat server it is giving this error:

```
No result defined for action FileUploadAction and result input
```

I tried not doing any thing in the execute method of the FileUploadAction class and just returning the SUCCESS. But it throwed the same error.

After some code debuggin i found this is because of the enctype="multipart/form-data". I modified the  FileUpload.jsp page with different enctype and deleted the `<s:file>` tag in jsp page and it didn't give any error.

Seems weird why it is working on my local tomcat server but not on a different one.
Should I change anything in the tomcat server to get the encype="multipart/form-data" working...

Comment: Please describe the differences in Tomcat environments. E.g. version, default config, etc.

Comment: I am having the same tomcat version 7.0.32. But mine is on a windows machine and the other one is linux which is giving that error. Where can i find the default config

Comment: Why not to create `input` result and see what error do you get after that?

Comment: it simply returns to the page assigned to the input result type. but the execute method is not even getting called.

Comment: Put `<s:actionerror/>` and `<s:fielderror/>` tags to input result page. Also change log level to debug and see if you get any exceptions.